# Send Prop from useEfect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

App.js ->

```
<Lobbies inGame={inGame} setLobby={setLobby} userName={userName} userKey={userKey}/>
```

Lobbies.js ->

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const Lobby = ({userKey, userName}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lobbyCreated){
            const db = firebase.database().ref(`Lobby/${lobbyKey}/players`);

            const listener = db.on('value', snapshot => {
                var fetchedTasks = [];

                fetchedTasks = snapshot.val();

                console.log(fetchedTasks[0]['game']);

                if (fetchedTasks[0]['game']) {
                    //SEND PROP BACK TO APP.JS BELOW
                    props.inGame(true, lobbyKey);
                }else{
                    if (fetchedTasks.length != players.length)  setPlayers(fetchedTasks);
                }
            });

            return () => db.off('value', listener);
        }
    });
};
```

How can I send a prop back to App.js from Lobbies.js using useEffect? (There is a comment where I want to send the props back) Thank you

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Comment: You've pretty much written it already - pass a callback (function) down as a prop and call it

Comment: Right now I get an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'inGame' of undefined

Comment: `({userKey, userName})` - you destructured some of your props. You definitely didn't assign all of them to an argument named `props`.

Comment: Yes you're right. It's fixed if I don't destruct my props in the Loby = ({us.. line. How can I destruct props with a function callback inside?

Answer (score 0):

You're already mostly there, you just need to call your callback `setLobby` in your `useEffect` hook.

The callback is already being passed down by `App`, simply destructure it from  your props (same way as any other prop) and call it with `lobbyKey` (or whatever else you want to "send back").